# Restarting Weblogic from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, weblogic

Need some pointers on how can we start or stop Weblogic server from Jenkins Box.
I didn't find any plugin already available.
Is there any shell or any script which we can reuse?
Thanks in Advance for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ant to control the server (You need a Weblogic Setup with AdminServer, ManagedServer and Nodemanager though)

Example for stopping the default Server (myserver, which in this case is my local AdminServer):

```
   <taskdef name="wlserver" classname="weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLServer">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${weblogic.basedir}/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar" />
            <pathelement location="${weblogic.basedir}/wlserver/server/lib/wls-api.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <target name="stop" description="Deletes build and dist directories.">
        <wlserver username="weblogic" password="weblogic" host="127.0.0.1" port="7001" action="shutdown"/>
    </target>
```

See also here for the complete ANT wlserver documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLPRG/ant_tasks.htm#WLPRG146